# Cannot select rows with MAX value only on a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select from the table `match` all the rows that have as field `gameweek` the highest value, so build this query:

```
SELECT m.id, MAX(m.gameweek) FROM `match` m WHERE round = 3
```

the problem's that this will return all the rows with `round = 3`

Comment: That query it's even valid SQL.. You should not be mixing a non-aggregate column with a aggregate column without using `GROUP BY`..  "the problem's that this will return all the rows with round = 3" Yea thats normal when you are using a `WHERE round = 3` filter ,,,  Provide example data and expected output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a comparison on each rows gameweek compared to the max gameweek in the table.  Try something like this.

```
SELECT m.id, m.gameweek
FROM `match` m 
WHERE round = 3 AND m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(gameweek) 
                                  FROM match);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is not that clear, and adding a group by may resolve your problem,

Still based on my understanding on your question, i think you need something below , it not even an ideal solution.  can give you more if you can clarify little more,

```
SELECT * from match where gameweek = ( select max(gameweek) FROM match);
```